# C++ Why the parenthesis?

Tags: c++

I found this code in a book:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void ChangesAreGood(int *myparam) {
    (*myparam) += 10;
    cout << "Inside the function:" << endl;
    cout << (*myparam) << endl;
}

int main() {
    int mynumber = 30;
    cout << "Before the function:" << endl;
    cout << mynumber << endl;

    ChangesAreGood(&mynumber);
    cout << "After the function:" << endl;
    cout << mynumber << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

It says:

```
(*myparam) += 10;
```

What difference would the following produce?

```
*myparam += 10;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### To answer your question:

In your example, there is no difference except in readability.

And, as the comments on this post all suggest, *please* don't use the parenthesis here...

### Interesting other cases

#### Using a property/method on the dereferenced object

On the other hand, there *is* a difference if you have something like

```
*myObject.myPropertyPtr += 10
```

compared to

```
(*myPointer).myProperty += 10
```

The names I chose here tell you what the difference is: the dereference operator `*` works on whatever is on its right hand side; in the first case the runtime will fetch the contents of `myObject.myPropertyPtr`, and dereference that, while in the second example it will dereference `myPointer`, and get `myProperty` from whatever is found on the object that `myPointer` points to.

The latter is so common that it even has its own syntax: `myPointer->myProperty`.

#### Using the `++` operator rather than `+=`

Another interesting example, which I thought of after reading another (now deleted) answer to this question, is the difference between these:

```
*myPointer++
(*myPointer)++
*(myPointer++)
```

The reason this is more interesting is because since `++` is a call like any other, and particularly doesn't deal with left and right hand side values, it is more ambiguous than your examples with `+=`. (Of course, they don't always make sense - sometimes you will end up trying to use the `++` operator on an object that doesn't support it - but if we limit our study to `int`s, this won't be a problem. And it should give you a compiler error anyway...)

Since you caught my curiosity, I conducted a small experiment testing these out. This is what I found out:

- `*myPointer++` does the same thing as `*(myPointer++)`, i.e. *first* increment the pointer, *then* dereference. This shouldn't be so surprising - it is what we'd expect knowing the result of running `*myObject.someProperty`.
- `(*myPointer)++` does what you'd expect, i.e. *first* dereference the pointer, *then* increment whatever the pointer pointed to (and leave the pointer as is).

Feel free to take a closer look at [the code I used to find this out](http://pastebin.com/hwwW1tXz) if you want to. Just save it to `dereftest.cpp`, compile with `g++ dereftest.cpp -o dereftest` (assuming you have G++ installed) and run with `./dereftest`.

Comment: “there is no difference except in readability” – yes, and the readability *without* parentheses is better.

Comment: There is a school of thought (that seems(very(prevalent)(amongst a certain())(() group of programmers who(()) like)(to claim()that obscure precedence (rules) make (excessive parentheses) necessary and that code with((())) more parentheses is more readable.) (such people are ((((((((((wrong)))))))))))))).

Comment: Thanks, it didn't seem like those were necessary, but pointers can be tricky so I wanted to be sure.

Comment: (Some people (think that (all programming (should be done (as if (they were programming (in LISP))))))).